# Magento 2 : Is it possible to switch extension from html to phtml

Tags: magento2

I have an html file and in this file I would like to call some block method

`app/design/frontend/Theme/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-addresses/form.html`

So I would like to add something like that :

```
<?php $store = $block->getStoreCode(); ?>
```

But the file being an html I can't do that.

My question is : Can I just change the form.html into a form.phtml without breaking anything ?
If I can't, how can I get the value I need ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant.

.Html files are used for the knockout components, their logic is in the .js files and their data comes from the php files.
.Phtml files for the blocks

If you want to add some extra logic to the html file - check out documentation and other sources about js components.